# Is there anyway for OpenStack to attach a physical disk directly?

Tags: openstack, cinder

I have a 2TB HDD, and I need to attach it to an instance directly. 
However, I don't know how to operate.

PS: I am not seeking for a method to add this HDD into "cinder-volumes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked "BDD" driver.. I'm still not sure about your question.. can you explain more..

BDD:
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/BlockDeviceDriver

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thks very much.